# Inserting into SQLITE in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, cocos2d-x, sql-insert

I am using cocos2d-x to create an app in android which needs to use a database.

I have used the following method, which I found whilst searching forums, to use SQLITE in cocos2d-x :

1. use CCFileUtils::getFileData() to read the sqlite file into a char*
2. use standard ofstrem to write the char* into a file in CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath() (in android is /data/data/xxx/xx)
3. than you can use sqlite3_open() to open the file in step 2

The problem I am having is that when I insert into the database, the original file is not being updated, i.e. the sqlite file in step 1 is not being updated and the file in step 2 is. Now when the app restarts, the data within the file in step 2 is overwritten therefore losing any insert data.

Here is my code :

```
string dbPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
dbPath.append("DischargedNew.mp3");
unsigned long tmpSize;
unsigned char *xmlData = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData("Discharged.mp3", "rb", &tmpSize);
FILE *fp = fopen(dbPath.c_str(), "wb");
fwrite(xmlData, tmpSize, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);

if(result = db->open((char*) dbPath.c_str()))
{
    CCLog("DB Opened");
    db->query("INSERT INTO USERS (Name, Username, Email) VALUES ('Test Test', 'T', 'test@test.com');");
}
else
{
    CCLog("OPENING WRONG, %d, MSG:%s", result, db->getError().c_str());
}


db->close();
```

Comment: So your problem is that *your code* overwrites the file with wrong data?

Comment: No. When the program quits, the file in step 1 (the original db file) is not being updated to take into account the new data which has been inserted.

If I tried to insert the same data in twice, one after another, the second time I would get an error because the Username is a primary key. However if I restart the program and execute the exact same query, it will do so successfully. And this would be because the original db file which is being used is not updated each time to reflect the changes.

Comment: You should not overwrite the writable copy when it already exists.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Do you actually know *why* you are creating a copy of the database?

Comment: I think because the assets folder is packed within the application package and therefore cannot be opened normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assets folder is read-only (and packed), so if you want to save any new/changed data, the only place where you can do this is in the writable directory.
This means that only the database in the writable directory contains correct and up-to-date data,, i.e., only this is the *actual* database.

The file in the assets folder should not be considered an actual database file; think of it as data that merely helps you to *initialize* the actual database.
After you've made any changes, the file in the assets folder is outdated.

When starting your program, check first if the database file in the writable directory exists.
Only if it is not yet there, initialize it by copying the file from the assets folder.

Comment: cheers mate thanks a lot. I think I was getting confused thinking that each time round the file in the writable directory had to be re-created therefore I kept getting the problem.

One more question, is there a way I can open up the database in the writable directory by passing it in as an argument to sqlite3 in terminal? Its just to track the data easily rather then executing SELECT statements and printing them.